# Show that $A/I$ need not an ideal of $R/I$ if $I \not\subseteq A$ for $I,A$ ideals of a given ring $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

So, in class we saw how from a given ring $R$ and one of its ideals (say $I$) we can form the quotient ring $R/I$ via the "sum cosets" $x + H$ for $x \in R$.

Also, if $S \subseteq R$ we defined $S/I$ as the set of all cosets $[x]$ such that $x$ belongs to $S$.

Here's my question: in several books we've seen that if $A$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $I \subseteq A$, then $A/I$ is an ideal of $R/I$. Its proof is not hard to see, but arises the doubt about whether or not $A/I$ is an ideal of $R/I$ if $A$ is an ideal $R$ such that $I \not\subseteq A$.

In particular, since $0$ belongs to $A$ for $A$ is an ideal, then $[0]$ belongs to $A/I$, just by definition... so at least some of the definition's clauses are met. However, when we proof that $A/I$ is indeed an ideal of $R/I$, we use the fact that $I \subseteq A$ when showing that $[x-y]$ belongs to $A/I$ if $[x], [y]$ belong to $A/I$.

Indeed, if $[x]$, $[y]$ belong to $A/I$ then there exist $h_x, h_y \in I$ and some $x',y' in A$ such that

$$x = x' + h_x$$
$$y = y' + h_y$$

Then:

$$x-y = x'-y' + h' \in A + I$$

Where $h' = h_x - h_y \in I$.

Here's where I want to find a counterexample, of an ideal $A$ such that $x'-y'+h'$ does not belong to $A$, and therefore $A/I$ would not be an ideal.

So far my only "counterexample" fails: let $R$ be the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers, $I = 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $A = 4\mathbb{Z}$ the sets of multiples of two and four, respectively. Then as $\mathbb{Z}$ in conmutative and cyclic with respect of $+$, $I$ and $A$ are ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$. Now, clearly $I \not\subseteq A$ for $2$ belongs to $I$ and not to $A$.

However, $R/I = {[0], [1]}$, and since $A \subseteq I$, then $A/I = {[0]}$... which is an ideal of $R/I$. So... is this a rare coincidence or a piece of evidence that my original assumption (that is, if $A$ does not contain $I$, $A/I$ is not an ideal of $R/I$) is false?

I'm somewhat new to ring theory, so I'm not quite familiar with rings and ideals other than integers, and I apologize if there's a flaw in my question.

Thanks for reading me so far, and have a nice day wherever you are!

Comment: Well, if $I\not\subseteq S$, then the coset $x+I$ is not fully contained in $S$ and thus $S/I$ should rather be $S/(S\cap I)$, and it doesn't necessarily embed into $R/I$ in general.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, been on finals! I'm not really sure how that impedes S/I being an ideal... could you provide an example?